# In iptables, does state ESTABLISHED require a later state NEW to make an ESTABLISHED connection?

Tags: iptables

When using the following rule:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

...do you need to add specific rules including the `NEW` states to allow for an `ESTABLISHED` connection?

Like so:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

...or are established connections made simply by `ACCEPTING` them?

I've read several tutorials on this, and I can't find this clarification anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the `NEW` state will be used to filter cases you don't wont to see as the first packet of a stream.

For instance :

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP
```

Will drop everything that doesn't look like a valid TCP `SYN` packet.

If your use case is to allow the world to connect to your server port 443, allow your server to reply and the connection to be established then you need to add the second rule but the `NEW` state is not *mandatory*.

So your configuration could either be :

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 443 -j ACCEPT 

iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Or

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT 

iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Or (better)

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT 

iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be enough to just do:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

Of course, for not accepting connections you already need to have either the policy set to DROP or to have a rule to DROP everything else.